# Browsing through multiple audio files for playback on Asterisk dialplan

Tags: centos7, asterisk, ivr, freepbx, dialplan

I'm trying to make a voicemail system on Asterisk 16, FreePBX 16 and CentOS 7 that lets people browse and choose from a list of prerecorded audio files. When the caller enters the menu to select the audio files, they're told how to browse through the different files. In the /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/ directory, the files are named from 1 to 3 (1.wav, 2.wav etc.) currently and the caller presses 1 to go to the previous file and 2 to go to the next file and 3 to select the current file they're listening to. The extensions part goes as such:

```
[prerecorded]
exten = s,1,NoOp(Pre-recorded messages)
same = n,Set(LOOP=0)
same = n,Set(FILE=1)
same = n(timeout),Wait(1)
same = n,Playback(browsing_tutorial)
same = n(loop),NoOp(Loop)
same = n,Background(${FILE})
same = n,WaitExten(5)

exten = 1,1,NoOp(Previous file)
same = n,Set(FILE=$[ ${FILE} - 1])
same = n,GoToIf($[ ${FILE} = 0 ]?:s,loop)
same = n,Playback(first_file)
same = n,Set(FILE=1)
same = n,GoTo(s,loop)

exten = 2,1,NoOp(Next file)
same = n,Set(FILE=$[ ${FILE} + 1])
same = n,GoToIf($[ ${FILE} = 4 ]?:s,loop)
same = n,Playback(last_file)
same = n,Set(FILE=3)
same = n,GoTo(s,loop)

exten = #,1,NoOp(Repeat)
same = n,GoTo(s,1)

exten = t,1,NoOp(No input)
same = n,Set(LOOP=$[ ${LOOP} + 1 ])
same = n,GoToIf($[ ${LOOP} > 2 ]?:s,timeout)
same = n,HangUp()
```

Doing it this way lets me browse through the files, but it warrants editing the extensions every time I add or remove any prerecorded files (which will be done often). If there's any way I can do this without needing to edit the extensions, it would be great.

Comment: What is your problem? To know when the end was reached?

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own application using native C/C++ interface in asterisk, if you skilled enough. See app_voicemail.c

You also can use AGI or ARI interface and control dialplan with scripted language

Other option is voicemail storage in db and db-driven app using func_odbc